# Display Client PC info using ASP.net MVC in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, powershell

I am currently trying to use powershell in an MVC asp.net project and I am trying to figure out how to display a Text on Click but Im coming from a python background. Currently my model, view and controller are loading but nothing happens when I click submit. The code i have currently is as follows and I guess im just not sure where to add the powershell script to update the file.

MODEL

```
using System.Diagnostics;
namespace GenesisMVC.Models
{
    public class IPAddress
    {
        public string? IP
        {
            get; set;
        }
        public static async Task<string> GetIpAddressTask()
        {
            const string fileName = "ipPower_Async.txt";

            if (File.Exists(fileName))
            {
                File.Delete(fileName);
            }

            var start = new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                FileName = "powershell.exe",
                UseShellExecute = false,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                Arguments = "Invoke-RestMethod ipinfo.io/ip",
                CreateNoWindow = true
            };


            using var process = Process.Start(start);
            using var reader = process.StandardOutput;

            process.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

            var IpAddress = reader.ReadToEnd();

            await File.WriteAllTextAsync(fileName, IpAddress);
            await process.WaitForExitAsync();

            return await File.ReadAllTextAsync(fileName);
        }
    }
}
```

VIEW

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
}

<div class="text-center">
    <h1 class="display-4">Welcome</h1>
    <p>Learn about <a href="https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core">building Web apps with ASP.NET Core</a>.</p>
</div>



@model GenesisMVC.Models.IPAddress
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.IP)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IP)
    <button type="submit">Get IP Address</button>
    
}
```

CONTROLLER

```
using GenesisMVC.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace GenesisMVC.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;

        public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public IActionResult Privacy()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [ResponseCache(Duration = 0, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
        public IActionResult Error()
        {
            return View(new ErrorViewModel { RequestId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier });
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult showIP(IPAddress model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                //TODO: IpAddress(model.IP);
            }
            
            return View("Index", model);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Running Powershell within an ASP.NET core app might be possible, but it would require you to elevate privileges so you are no longer running within a sandbox on the server. It is unclear why you would want to add that complexity if you are just starting out. IP addresses of both the client (browser) and server are readily available from `HttpContext` (inside the controller), but it isn't clear from your question which one you are after.

Comment: I want to get the IP address of the current users system. I will also want to use power shell for make and model numbers, but first I guess I am trying to figure out how to see the output using a powershell script

Comment: https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/108/how-to-get-operative-system-and-hardware-information-with-electron-framework

https://github.com/ElectronNET/electron.net-api-demos

so apparently what i want to do isn't actually possible for mvc unless you use this library and once you understand how to use electron then you can use the demo available on the tutorial.

Comment: You can remove the `if (File.Exists())` check and just call `File.Delete()`. If the file doesn't exist, nothing happens, so the check is redundant and adds extra disk I/O, which is about the slowest thing you can do in a single computer.

Comment: thank you for the tip but im still confused on the question @JoelCoehoorn

Answer (score 0):

FYI everyone looking at this, the developer https://github.com/ElectronNET/electron.net-api-demos made a decent tutorial for this but lets just go with im the type of developer who is kinda dumb but competent.

So Basically your gonna want to create a type script file using the index.ts file as a template

once you have a type script file place your custom JS in the onHostRead() part of the script

build it

this will create the js file and make it look similar to the other example files.

create a controller for your custom js like hosthook.cs, this is called the mainfunction in the api demo

add front facing logic to your software. ....so still testing idk If i got it right just yet

This did not work in visual studio code , I used visual studio 2022

dont install the type script nuget package visual studio recommends , its not in the documentation, will break build.

sometimes the people capable are too busy to help so dive deep in the code and get good (talking to myself here)

ipController.cs

```
using ElectronNET.API;
using ElectronNET.API.Entities;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System.Linq;

namespace ElectronNET_API_Demos.Controllers
{
public class IPController : Controller
{
public IActionResult Index()
{
if (HybridSupport.IsElectronActive)
{
Electron.IpcMain.On("start-hoosthook", async (args) =>
{
var mainWindow = Electron.WindowManager.BrowserWindows.First();
var options = new OpenDialogOptions
{
Properties = new OpenDialogProperty[]
{
OpenDialogProperty.openDirectory
}
};
var folderPath = await Electron.Dialog.ShowOpenDialogAsync(mainWindow, options);

                var resultFromTypeScript = await Electron.HostHook.CallAsync<string>("get-ip-address", folderPath);
                Electron.IpcMain.Send(mainWindow, "ip-address-found", resultFromTypeScript);
            });
        }

        return View();
    }
}
}
```

ipAddress.ts

```
// @ts-ignore
import * as Electron from "electron";
import { Connector } from "./connector";
import { IPAddress } from "./ipAddress";

export class HookService extends Connector {
constructor(socket: SocketIO.Socket, public app: Electron.App) {
super(socket, app);
}

onHostReady(): void {
    // execute your own JavaScript Host logic here
    var os = require("os");
    var result = console.log(os.networkInterfaces);
        
    return result;
}
}
```

ipAddress.js

```
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
exports.HookService = void 0;
const connector_1 = require("./connector");
class HookService extends connector_1.Connector {
constructor(socket, app) {
super(socket, app);
this.app = app;
}
onHostReady() {
// execute your own JavaScript Host logic here
var os = require("os");
var result = console.log(os.networkInterfaces);
return result;
}
}
exports.HookService = HookService;
//# sourceMappingURL=ipAddress.js.map
```